# Is SQL Studio part of SQL Server Express edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

Is SQL Studio part of SQL Server 2005 Express edition?

If not, how do you restore a database to the server if there is no Studio to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free express edition of SQL Server Management Studio as well:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796

Comment: Yeah this is the best way to go. Just downlaod the SQL management tools.

Comment: Thanks, but is the studio express part of the sql-server express package? I found studio express on my machine and I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: It depends what components were installed to begin with, so I cannot answer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can download SQL Server Express with Advanced Services [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&displaylang=en). It will give you management studio and reporting features as well.